# Specify output type of arithmetic expressions

Tags: java, math, types, output, expression

Suppose:

```
byte b1 = 10; 
byte b2 = 20;
short p = 200;
int n = 500; 
long q = 100;
float x = 2.5f;
double y = 5.25;
```

What is the output type of the arithmetic expression below please:

```
b1*q*2./x
```

I've tried this so far:

```
byte * long * double / float
byte * long * ( double / float ) 
byte * long * ( double / double ) 
byte * long * double
byte * ( long * double ) //I've just added parentheses
byte * ( double * double ) 
byte * double 
cast(double)byte * double = double
```

So the result type is double.

Is that correct ?

Comment: Wouldn't you also be interested in how the answerer arrived at their conclusion?

Comment: @laune
No it is not so difficult, but I would like to know if my answer is correct :)

Comment: Once there is a double in the expression and you don't cast it it remains double, and a floating point literal is double unless it has the suffix f.

Comment: @laune, thank you so much for you answer :)